# How to handle throw exceptions inside finally block in java

Tags: java, sonarqube, try-catch, try-catch-finally, try-finally

In java, it is not recommended to throw exceptions inside `finally` section in `try-chatch` block due to hide the propagation of any unhandled `throwable` which was thrown in the `try` or `catch` block. This practice is a `blocker` level violation according to default sonar profile.

> Sonar Error: Remove this throw statement from this finally block.

Please consider the following code snippet.

e.g.: close input stream inside the finally block, and handle possible exceptions might be occurred when closing the stream.

```java
    public void upload(File file) {
        ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(file.toInputStream());
        try {
            String uploadLocation = Files.simplifyPath(this.fileLocation + "/" + file.getName());
            c.put(bis, uploadLocation);
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            throw new IllegalTargetException("Error occurred while uploading " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Exception occurred while closing Input stream " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

It would be grateful if you can show the conventional way of handling these situations.

Comment: as a sidenote, the more smooth solution would be the usage of [try-with-ressources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Think about what happens when the finally-block is being executed after throwing that `IllegalTargetException` and another `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown. Which of those would the caller get? The same is true with return-statements in finally-blocks, you'd tamper with the control flow which will lead to disaster.

Comment: The general problem here is that throwing from `finally{}` hides any exceptions that the main body has thrown.  Use try-with-resources for this sort of thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid throw clause in finally block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187304/how-to-avoid-throw-clause-in-finally-block)

Comment: `try-with-ressources` is often relevant but in case when you want to trace the exception that prevents the stream from being closed or you have to perform a recovery processing, it hides the problem.

Comment: According to your advises, try-with-resource is the best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best way to handle this problem is to use `try-with-resource`. But if someone  want to close the connection manually and show the exception of the `try` or `catch` block without hiding, following code snippet is the solution.

```
public void upload(File file) throws IOException {
    ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(file.toInputStream());
    SftpException sftpException = null;
    try {
        String uploadLocation = Files.simplifyPath(this.fileLocation + "/" + file.getName());
        c.put(bis, uploadLocation);
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        sftpException = e;
        throw new IllegalTargetException("Error occurred while uploading " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (sftpException != null) {
            try {
                bis.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                sftpException.addSuppressed(t);
            }
        } else {
            bis.close();
        }
    }
}
```